# How to start remote debugging of .NET Core 2.x app on Windows?

Tags: .net-core, remote-debugging, visual-studio-2019

How do I start a remote debugging session with a .NET Core 2.x app? I know I can attach to a running process, but I can only get F5 to "launch process & debug on remote machine" to work for .NET Framework.

In the past, I've set my build output folder one that the remote machine can access, and everything has worked fine (this was with .NET Framework)

I'm using VS2019 on Windows, and the remote machine is also Windows.

The .NET Core app is a console app (it's actually ASP MVC Core with Kestrel)